# Check if page is in Iframe for Google Chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, iframe, window

I have tried many properties of window to see if a page in an iframe can tell if it is in an iframe. I have tried:

```
if(top.location!= self.location) //doesn't work in Google Chrome
   alert("I am in an iframe!")
```

And this doesn't work (works on all browsers but Chrome). I am writing a userscript for Firefox and Chrome but Chrome really doesn't behave. Is there a way to tell if Chrome can detect if its page is in an iframe?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/hpVec/ It seems to be working fine in Chrome.

Comment: var in_iframe = (window.location != window.parent.location);

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This works for frames I would assume it also works with iFrames

```
if (top === self) { 
  // no frame
} else { 
  //frame 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`window.frameElement` is supported in even the most ancient browsers. It identifies an iframe, embed, or object in which the current window is embedded.

```
if(!!window.frameElement){
  //code to be executed if we are in an iframe
}
```

[More here.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/frameElement)