# Magnific Popup: load specific div into iframe

Tags: jquery, iframe, magnific-popup

I seen in the documentation that in magnific popup it is possible to load a specific div via the ajax option into the lightbox.

> parseAjax: function(mfpResponse) {
>      // mfpResponse.data is a "data" object from ajax "success" callback
>      // for simple HTML file, it will be just String
>      // You may modify it to change contents of the popup
>      // For example, to show just #some-element:
>      // mfpResponse.data = $(mfpResponse.data).find('#some-element');
>
> // mfpResponse.data must be a String or a DOM (jQuery) element

is there a similar way to load a div from a local url (not external site) into an iframe to display only a part of page ? 
Any hints are welcome

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This worked for me:

on the pages loaded into the iFrame I did a check if the page is in a frame

```
if (top === self) { 
  // no frame
} else { 
  $("#mydiv1, #mydiv2").hide(); //frame 
}
```

as found on:
[Check if page is in Iframe for Google Chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5278676/check-if-page-is-in-iframe-for-google-chrome)

but it is just a quick workaround, any more elegant solutions are welcome